# Query error - SparkContext.assertNotStopped

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I'm working with Spark Structured Streaming for communication with streams and I'm performing a query and I'm getting this error but I don't know why.

I receive the data from a stream and with a select I extract the data that I am going to send to another stream.

**My code is developed with Scala**

```
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.defaultParallelism
```

I have tried to import after creating the Spark session but it does not use the implicits._ import at all.

What is the reason for this error?
It's because of spark.stop ?